# Is this derivation correct?

Tags: probability

Assume a set of parallel components as follows:

```
           |
       ---------
       |        | 
      ----     -----
      |A |     | B | 
      ----     -----
        |        | 
        ----------
            |
```

When component A fails, I know that B will be rendered active with a probability of 0.80 (say, $k$).

Therefore, if I want the system to be up with a probability of 0.999 (say, S), what is the number of parallel components needed? The way I was thinking of deriving this number is as follows:

$Availability~of~the~components~\geq~Desired~availability$

Probability that one component will fail = $(1-k)$

For $n$ components, this is $(1-k)^n$

Therefore,

$1 - (1-k)^n \geq S$
$\Rightarrow n \leq \frac{log(1-S)}{log(1-k)}$

This will give the right hand side to be a fraction. Should I be taking a ceil of this number of a floor? (because a fraction does not make sense for the number of components). Any suggestions?

Comment: Notice that $\log(1-k) < 0$ for probability $k$, both for natural log or common log. Therefore, you have to switch your inequality sign.

Comment: @peterwhy: So you mean to say, $n \geq \frac{log(1-S)}{log(1-k)}$?

Comment: Yes, if your $r$ is $k$

Comment: @peterwhy: Yes, sorry. That was a typo. So that's why my answer was not making a sense - I believe now I can justify a ceiling function. Thank you so much. If you don't mind, can you write a brief derivation of where this switch occurs? Is it when I take logarithm on both sides?

Comment: By the way, this is only correct if parallel components fail independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\log(1-k) < 0$ for probability $k$, both for natural log or common log. Therefore, you have to switch your inequality sign when dividing both sides by $\log(1-k)$.

$$\begin{align}
1 - (1-k)^n \ge& S\\
1 - S \ge& (1-k)^n\\
\log(1-S) \ge& \log\left[(1-k)^n\right]\\
\log(1-S) \ge& n\log(1-k)\\
\frac{\log(1-S)}{\log(1-k)} \le& n\\
n \ge& \frac{\log(1-S)}{\log(1-k)}
\end{align}$$

You need NOT switch inequality sign when taking logarithm on both sides, as common log and natural log are both strictly increasing functions.

For your case, $S=.999$ and $k=.8$. Therefore, $n \ge 4.29$. If you test $n=4$, $S=.9984$; if you test $n=5$, $S=.99968\ge.999$.